# SIGABRT error in xcode: NSMutableArray fails to load all objects creating null reference

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, nsmutablearray, sigabrt

I am trying to create a quiz app. My code should load the questions & answers from a CSV and then display them randomly. On the simulator, it works well up until at least question 85. After which it starts throwing a `SIGABRT` error:

```
2011-12-27 19:03:22.026 100Q_Capitals[5369:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 99 beyond bounds [0 .. 95]'
```

Here's the code that I have used:

Both `questionTota`l and `questionCount100` are initialized as int, and then to set up the array and read from the CSV, I wrote this

```
NSString *pathA = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                   [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                   @"/right.wav"];
NSURL *filePathA = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathA isDirectory:NO];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePathA, &rightSound);

NSMutableArray *newArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:200];
NSMutableArray *newArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:200];
NSMutableArray *newArray3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:200];
NSMutableArray *newArray4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:200];
NSMutableArray *newArray5 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:200];

self.questionArray = newArray1;
self.correctArray = newArray2;
self.wrongArray1 = newArray3;
self.wrongArray2 = newArray4;
self.wrongArray3 = newArray5;

[newArray1 release];
[newArray2 release];
[newArray3 release];
[newArray4 release];
[newArray5 release];

NSString* pathCSV = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"capitals1" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathCSV encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
if (!fileString) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading file.");
}
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:fileString];
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n,;"]];

NSString *id = nil, *hashOne = nil, *hashTwo = nil, *hashThree = nil, *hashFour = nil, *hashFive=nil;
while ([scanner scanUpToString:@"," intoString:&id] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"," intoString:&hashOne] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"," intoString:&hashTwo] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"," intoString:&hashThree] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"," intoString:&hashFour] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"\n" intoString:&hashFive])
{
//  NSLog(@"id:%@, 1:%@, 2:%@, 3:%@:, 4:%@, 5:%@", id, hashOne, hashTwo, hashThree, hashFour, hashFive);

    [questionArray addObject:hashOne];
    [correctArray addObject:hashTwo];
    [wrongArray1 addObject:hashThree];
    [wrongArray2 addObject:hashFour];
    [wrongArray3 addObject:hashFive];


    questionTotal++;
}   

appDelegate.saveArrayQ = questionArray;
appDelegate.saveArrayC = correctArray;
appDelegate.saveArray1 = wrongArray1;
appDelegate.saveArray2 = wrongArray2;
appDelegate.saveArray3 = wrongArray3;
```

And then to access the array and display it as part of the quiz, I wrote this (the first `NSString*question ...` line is where the SIGABRT error occurred).

```
showQuestion{

for (UIButton *thisButton in [self.view subviews])
{
    if ([thisButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        if (thisButton.tag != 100) 
        {
            [thisButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectAnswer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }else{}
    }else{}
}

[answerButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[answerButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[answerButton3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[answerButton4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

secondsLeft = appDelegate.timerLength;

NSString *timerString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"0:%02d",secondsLeft];
timerLabel.text = timerString;
[timerString release];

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateDuration) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

int q = arc4random() % 100;
q = abs(q);

NSString *num = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",appDelegate.saveQ100 + 1];
numberLabel.text = num;
[num release];

NSString *question = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[appDelegate.saveArrayQ objectAtIndex:q]];
NSString *choice1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[appDelegate.saveArrayC objectAtIndex:q]];
NSString *choice2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[appDelegate.saveArray1 objectAtIndex:q]];
NSString *choice3 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[appDelegate.saveArray2 objectAtIndex:q]];
NSString *choice4 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[appDelegate.saveArray3 objectAtIndex:q]];
```

etc
etc
etc

Would really be grateful if someone can help me out here. I have spent 2 days trying to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Help me, How to given questions for the Quiz , technique . Thank You

Answer (score 1):

When you generate a number which is stored in q , it will be a number from 0 to 99 . But from error message you have an array that have only 96 elements. You can not access an element that is not in array. I do not really know what you want to do , but just try to generate numbers from 0 to 95

```
int q = arc4random() % 96;
```

Comment: Thanks. All am trying to do is to show 100 question and answers, one set at a time. I believe I have set up the array well. I have 172 entries in the csv and set up the array to take in up to 200 entries. So I would have expected to have at least 172 entries in the array. Why then is the code saying there is nothing in the array?

Comment: And to add further, it varies on when it throws the SIGABRT. It has done so on 84, 89, 93, 95 and 97. So somehow, the array is not loading all the 172 entries that I have on the csv. I have also swapped csv files just to make sure that the error is not due to a corrupted csv file. Thanks

Comment: first: why you are using abs(), your number will be just positive even you will not use abs, second : if you initWithCapacity is 200 that does not mean that you have 200 elements. It's like saying that : i alloc and init an array that may be will containt 200 elements, not necessary to be 200 elements. So you can do this : you will generate a number depending on array lenght : int q = [appDelegate.saveArrayQ count] , do it for each array

Comment: Thanks very much devXcode. I ve noted your observations. However, the problem is that I really want to be able to show at least 100 questions & answers. So I am puzzled why my array will not fetch and hold the required number of entries. Have I done anything wrong in setting up the array?

Comment: if you want questionArray (for example) to have at least 100 questions you must add at least 100 objects , so first you should verify the containing of your file where you fetch string for NSScaner, and check last value questionTotal if its lower that 100 . I did not worked with NSScaner in deep , but i think when you try with scanUpToString and met every time "," carachter it will be same value for hashOne,hashTwo,etc .Try to see value for all these ivars

Comment: Better yet, rather than limiting the index to some hard-coded number, limit it to the number of elements in the array, whatever that number may be.